# How to pass the value to Ansible playbook from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins

I need to pass the value to Ansible playbook yml from Jenkins

Could you please help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because I was looking for this recently, in addition to the answer above, on any ansible build step, you can click on advanced, and then extra variables and add a variable there.  If you have a choice step that stores the value of the choice in a variable, you can reference that choice variable in a later extra variable by using ${choice_variable}.

Answer (score 8):

Ansible-Playbook plugin didn't give you the full power off Ansible with jenkins, I can share the method that how I am using ansible with jenkins which will give you exactly the same power as you are using it from the command line.

Let's say, you job name is "`stackoverflow`" then you can put the `ansible-scripts` directory inside the `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/stackoverflow/workspace` and use it in your jenkins job like this:

[image]
After that you can use the power of shell environment:
[image]
Once you will configure this job then you can use it as you are normally using the ansible from the command line:
[image]

Please adjust the settings as per your environment.

Hope this will help you or other who want to use ansible from the jenkins.

Comment: Thanks @Arbab Nazar